# Multi-label confusion matrix

Tags: python, r, weka, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I am working with multi-label classification on actual data and predicted data from my classifier. The actual data consist of three classes (c1,c2 and c3) and in the same way the predicted data also consist of three classes (c1,c2 and c3). The data is as follows

```
Actual_data     Predicted_data
c1 c2 c3         c1 c2 c3
1  1  0          1  1  1
1  1  0          1  0  1
1  0  1          0  1  1
0  1  1          1  0  0
1  0  0          1  1  0
1  1  1          1  0  1
```

In multi-label classification a document may belongs to more than one class. In the above data 1 represent document belongs to the particular class and 0 represents document does not belongs to the particular class.

The first row of Actual_data represents the document belongs to class c1 and c2 and does not belong to class c3. Similarly the first row of predicted_data represents document belongs to class c1,c2 and c3.

Initially I have used R-programming for finding confusion matrix between actual data and predicted data. I kept these data frames in y_actual and y_predict.

```
y_actual<-as.matrix(Actual_data)
y_predict<-as.matrix(Predicted_data)
xtab<-table(y_actual,y_predict)
```

The output xtab is

```
            y_predict
 y_actual     0 1
            0 1 5
            1 5 7
```

Then I have created confusion matrix using caret package of R which is given below

```
library(caret) 
confusionMatrix(xtab)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics
                   y_predict
           y_actual 0 1
                  0 1 5
                  1 5 7

               Accuracy : 0.4444          
                 95% CI : (0.2153, 0.6924)
     No Information Rate : 0.6667          
     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.9856          

              Kappa : -0.25           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.0000          

            Sensitivity : 0.16667         
            Specificity : 0.58333         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.16667         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.58333         
             Prevalence : 0.33333         
         Detection Rate : 0.05556         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.33333         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.37500         

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

In this case I have not got multi-label confusion matrix instead I got binary label confusion matrix. I want a confusion matrix with c1,c2,c3 in y-actual as well as y-predict instead 0,1 in y-actual and y-predict.

Then I have searched in the internet, utiml package is used for multi-label classification in R but that does not provided the desired output. Then I tried scikit package of python for multi-label classification, the code is given below.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
y_actual = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                     [1, 1, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1],
                     [0, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1]])
y_predict = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 1],
                      [1, 0, 0],
                      [1, 1, 0],
                      [1, 0, 1]])
matrix = multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_actual, y_predict)
print(matrix)
print(classification_report(y_actual,y_predict))
```

The output of the program is

```
    [[[0 1]
      [1 4]]

    [[0 2]
      [3 1]]

    [[1 2]
      [1 2]]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.80      0.80      0.80         5
           1       0.33      0.25      0.29         4
           2       0.50      0.67      0.57         3

   micro avg       0.58      0.58      0.58        12
   macro avg       0.54      0.57      0.55        12
weighted avg       0.57      0.58      0.57        12
 samples avg       0.53      0.61      0.54        12
```

In this case also I am not getting the output label wise. Can any one help me what kind of package need to be used to obtain the multi-label confusion matrix for the above actual and predicted data in any platform(R-programming, python or weka). In the output the confusion matrix need to be a 3*3 matrix for c1,c2 and c3 of y_actual and y_predict.

```
                    y_predict
    y_actual       c1 c2 c3
                c1 4
                c2    1
                c3       2
```

Here the diagonal element suggest that actually it belongs to c1 and classifier predicted it belongs c1. Similarly for c2 and c3. My question is how to obtain other values of the confusion matrix as it is multi-label classification. This problem is not a multi-class classification problem it is a multi-label classification problem.

Comment: @Kaushik
I am hoping to evaulate my classifiers, for various algorithms. So I was thinking of making a conf matrix with rows and cols representing true topics and pred topics. then for metrics, i will compute
            precision recall Classification-False
Overall        #         #                #
topic1         #         #                #
topic2         #         #                #


unless there is noather way that i shuold be evaulating multi label classification. i would love to know your thoughts. thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Because label wise confusion matrix means you will have L number of confusion matrices, if you have L labels. I think you want to capture the labels which were corrected predicted as a positive in a single matrix, like as in your example? In that case it is not a confusion matrix, as it will only have a diagonal. It is essentially the list of the predictions which were correct?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the way your data is represented so that it matches what `caret` or `sklearn` expect, in terms of the confusion matrix. If you consider that each cell in a confusion matrix represents a discrete class prediction (i.e., "for this class, we predict this, but we actually see this"), then you can see that there is no way to actually construct such a matrix for your example, where classes can take on simultanous values.

With that in mind, in your example, you don't actually have three discrete categories--you have 8.

That means for each row of observations, given the three categorical values that exist, your data point could take on:

```
none of the categories
only c1
c1&c2
c1&c3
only c2
c2&c3
only c3
all categories
```

All you would need to do is add a new column to your dataframe that recodes your three existing target columns so that, where the new column takes on 1 or the 8 values indicating each of these combinations.

Here is one example of a solution:

```
#Recreating your data

Actual_data <- cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                     c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                     c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
)

colnames(Actual_data) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")

Predicted_data <- cbind(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                        c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                        c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
)

colnames(Predicted_data) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")

#To make it easy to recode everything, we can convert these two objects into dataframes:

Predicted_data <-as.data.frame(Predicted_data)
Actual_data <- as.data.frame(Actual_data)

#Next, we make a simple function that goes through each row and recodes the class 
#combinations to a distinct category

set_class_combinations <- function(df){
    df$target <- 0
    for (i in nrow(df)){
        df$target[df$c1 == 0 & df$c2 == 0 & df$c3 == 0] <- 1
        df$target[df$c1 == 1 & df$c2 == 0 & df$c3 == 0] <- 2
        df$target[df$c1 == 1 & df$c2 == 1 & df$c3 == 0] <- 3
        df$target[df$c1 == 1 & df$c2 == 0 & df$c3 == 1] <- 4
        df$target[df$c1 == 0 & df$c2 == 1 & df$c3 == 0] <- 5
        df$target[df$c1 == 0 & df$c2 == 1 & df$c3 == 1] <- 6
        df$target[df$c1 == 0 & df$c2 == 0 & df$c3 == 1] <- 7
        df$target[df$c1 == 1 & df$c2 == 1 & df$c3 == 1] <- 8
    }
    return(df)
}

#With the function, we can add a new "target" column to our respective dataframes

Predicted_data <- set_class_combinations(Predicted_data)
Actual_data <- set_class_combinations(Actual_data)

#As your example does not include all available combinations, we just need to ensure that we 
#account for this when we set the factor levels (1 through 8) and call the `confusionMatrix` function

cm <- confusionMatrix(factor(Predicted_data$target, levels = 1:8), factor(Actual_data$target, levels = 1:8))

print(cm)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and your answer. But I have two quires; the first one is I do have around 15 classes; if I go as your coding technique, I need 2^n test cases; it will increase the complexity of the code. Secondly, for an actual document, suppose the number 6 as per your technique and my classifier predicted number 7 as per your technique (means doc initially belongs c1,c2 does not belong c3, and after classification, it belongs to all the category). Even if it is matching with c1 and c2, it is treated differently in the confusion matrix as the predicted number is 7.

Comment: It’s quite easy to get a 3x3 confusion matrix if the categories are exclusive, but it’s not possible in a 3x3 format if the categories are not exclusive as you outlined. The challenge here is not a technical/coding one, it’s more about what is possible with a confusion matrix.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.I am working to find out other possibility. Actually I am very new to multi-label classification. I am not able connect my code with existing multi-label algorithms in r and python.